# ERROR: Failed to resolve issue after changing classpath on android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After changing the classpath on dependencies on build.gradle to `3.3.2`, I'm getting this Error:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
layout:1.1.3
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

This is my build.gradle(Project: MyApplication) file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        //"/home/hb3hbahan1/Android-Studio/android-studio/gradle/gradle-3.3.2.pom"
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is the build.gradle(Module: App) file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

EDIT: I just commented out the entire dependencies except for the 3rd line on build.gradle(Module: app) and the errors are gone. is that gonna affect my future debugs etc?

Comment: You can try get dependencies again via " File > Sync Project with Gradle File"

Comment: Your code is compiling even after removing those dependencies means it was never required in your code. If it is required in future you can try to use androidx support library. e.g. implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'